# Is there a way to return a vector more efficiently

Tags: c++, return, stdvector

Is there a way to return a vector like this in c++ (python code)

```
return [i, j]
```

as if it was:

```
return {i, j}
```

or something like that, instead of creating a vector before hand, pushing values and then returning that vector, like in this

```
vector<int> v;
        loop
            loop
                condition
                    v.push_back(i);
                    v.push_back(j);
                }   
            }
        }
return v;
```

so you could just return {i , j} instead of the push_back statements,

also, if this would actually decrease the runtime or not.

Comment: research `std::initializer_list`. this is why it exists. the problem was solved about 10 years ago. to answer more, we'll need to know what those `loop`s and `condition` are, so for now I VTC as incomplete.

Comment: The feature you are looking for is Structured binding. It is avail since c++17.

Comment: Your Python returns a list with two elements and seems unrelated to what you're describing.

Comment: @SebastianH No, it's not. Structured binding has nothing to do with this (only coincidentally using the same brackets). They want to be able to do `return {bunch, of, values}` instead of `result.push_back(bunch); result.push_back(of); result.push_back(values)`. And they can, with `vector`'s standard constructor from `std::initializer_list` since C++11. However, if they also want to combine this with loops and conditions in some vague way, that may or may not be possible, but who really knows given how the question is currently written without context on that.

Comment: @molbdnilo The python code is related as it is what I was trying to do in C++, but expressed in another language(Python).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to return a vector like this
>
> ...
>
> ```
> return {i, j}
> ```

Yes.

> also, if this would actually decrease the runtime or not.

Typically not. At least not significantly.